# How do you run a custom task against multiple servers using capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm playing around with a cluster to run some load tests. How can I run a command on all of them? This works fine:

```
role :lt1, "root@184.106.65.194"
role :lt2, "root@184.106.70.52"
role :lt3, "root@184.106.69.138"
role :lt4, "root@184.106.70.42"
role :lt5, "root@184.106.70.90" 
role :lt6, "root@184.106.98.158"
role :lt7, "root@184.106.70.89" 
role :lt8, "root@184.106.70.58" 
role :lt9, "root@184.106.64.187"
role :lt10, "root@184.106.97.57"

task :date, :roles => [:lt1] do
  run "date"
end
```

But the minute I try to change `:roles` to `[:lt1, :lt2]`, it just hangs forever.

I've also tried almost the exact same thing with servers that have named addresses (`example.something.com`), and it works fine.

What's the right way to do this, and how can I avoid it hanging?

**When I only do one:**

```
  * executing `date'
  * executing "date"
    servers: ["184.106.65.194"]
    [root@184.106.65.194] executing command
 ** [out :: root@184.106.65.194] Wed Jan 26 19:56:16 UTC 2011
    command finished
```

**When I do two**

```
* executing `date'
* executing "date"
  servers: ["184.106.65.194", "184.106.70.52"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to capistrano v2.5.19 seems to have fixed it.